# wrong when import python code in "programming collective intelligence"

Tags: python

I'm reading programming collective intelligence book. In chapter 2 I've problem when doing this step

```
>>>from recommendations import critics
```

the terminal show me this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name critics
```

the whole code is

```
  # A dictionary of movie critics and their ratings of a small
     # set of movies
     critics = {'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
      'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
      'The Night Listener': 3.0},
     'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
      'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
      'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
     'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
      'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
     'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
      'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
      'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5},
     'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
      'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
      'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0},
     'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
      'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
     'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.5,'You, Me and Dupree':1.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}
```

Comment: Is `recommendations.py` stored in a place where you can access it? Have you appended the path where that file is to `sys.path`? If you haven't, then Python is not looking in the "right" folder for `recommendations.py`.

Comment: Copy the `recommendations.py` to the location from where you are starting the `python` REPL.

Comment: @not_a_robot thank you for your replay, I do all these steps but still the terminal show same message.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read this book but it looks like you need to download "recommendations" module to complete the example. Here it is https://github.com/arthur-e/Programming-Collective-Intelligence/blob/master/chapter2/recommendations.py 
P.S.
You need to put this file in your work directory